# How can I transition a flexbox sliding in from the left, to be centered on the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have a flexbox with css properties that look something like this:

```
#root {
    display: flex;
    width: 85%;
    border: 1px #F2F0F0 solid;
    margin: 0 -100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    transition-property: margin;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

This pushes my flexbox entirely out of the screen, to the left. I now want to slide it in to the right, however, I read that you cannot use transition with computed values, like `margin: 0 auto` which is the css I would like my flexbox to transition to, in order to center my flexbox responsively to the center of my screen.

How can I make this possible? I'm sure I'm missing something simple. My currently transition is just to a margin that isn't responsive, nor centered.

```
#root.slide-in {
    margin: 0 2%;
}
```

Edit:

My flexbox is inside of a container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- I want to center this flexbox -->
    <div id="root" class="flexbox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of animating `margin`, you should use the CSS property `transform`, which is was created to use for this kind of transitions. Then you can leave the CSS layout properties such as margin and position intact. Unlike `margin`, changing `transform` will never change the positioning of surrounding elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#root {
  align-self: center;
  width: 85%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 1s transform;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}
```

```html
<div class=container onclick="document.querySelector('#root').classList.toggle('hidden')">
  <div id=root> This is #root </div>
  <p>click to hide or show #root</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As someone also mentioned in another answer, you don't really need to use the `margin: auto` trick with flexbox. Instead you can use nested flex elements with `justify-content: center` to center child elements. This can be used in both the horizontal and vertical axis.

Comment: Can you clarify on this a bit? so I have a flexbox nested inside of a regular div container. I am trying to center the flexbox itself (ie. `#root`) inside of that regular div container, which is NOT a flexbox. Isn't the only way to do that, by using `margin: auto`? @Håken Lid

Comment: The parent element should have css style `display: flex; justify-content: center;`. You can add a intermediate wrapper div if you don't want the outer element to display as flex.

Answer (score 1):

See below. Hope this helps.

```css
#root {
    display: flex;
    width: 85%;
    border: 1px #F2F0F0 solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    left: -100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    animation: slideIn 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try justify-content: center, this centers elements horizontally whereas the align-items centers the elements vertically.

Answer (score 0):

In yout case, you can set the correct margin, since your width is 85%.

Note also that the fact that the element is flex doesn't have relevance, it would affect only the children of the element, but not the position of itself

```css
#root {
    width: 85%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: 0 -100%;
    height: 600px;
    transition-property: margin;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

body:hover #root {
    margin: 0 7.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```